# How to make a fade out border for uiview

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, calayer

How to implement a one-side and fade out border for `UIView`. I'm sorry that I don't have enough reputation to post a screenshot. But there is an example in `iOS` native Contact app. If you click on "+" then "add phone", there will be a vertically line, which is exactly what I want.

I have already implemented one-side border for an `UIView` but can't find out a way to make it fade out. I tried `CIFilter`, which didn't work. Then I noticed that this fade out effect is simliar to shadow. I tried to simulate the fade out by setting shadow but failed again.

Thanks for any answer and suggestion in advance.

Comment: Do you want to fade to another RGB colour ?

Comment: @SPlatten Just fade from Gray to White. I finished it using CAGradientLayer  suggested by answer below. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `CAGradientLayer`:

```
let layer = CAGradientLayer()
layer.colors = [UIColor.white.cgColor, UIColor.gray.cgColor]
// play around with layer.locations and layer.{startPoint|endPoint} to suit your needs
```

You can then subclass `UIView` and override its `layerClass` to return the gradient layer, and then 
size and position that view as you please:

```
override class func layerClass() -> AnyClass {
   return CAGradientLayer.self
}
// configure the layer with color, end/start and locations in init()
```

This allows you to drop that view in anywhere and use auto layout to size and position it as you please.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm playing with layer in UIView' init right now. I think i'm on the right track but just having a question: Why does UIView set its layer property as get-only? Why not simply let us set layer property rather than first return layerClass then configure layer in init (I had no experience about CALayer before this). I'm sorry that I voted for your answer but it didn't count because I don't have enough reputation at this moment.

Comment: A `UIView` is backed by a `CALayer`, so UIKit needs to know the layer's type at the time of initialisation (note that `layerClass` returns the type, not an instance, of the layer). That is, the view's backing layer cannot be changed after it has been created. If you find my answer suitable I'm sure you can mark it as the correct one :-)

Comment: I have already finished what I was after using CAGradientLayer.  Thank you very much. And your explanation about CALayer solved my question. Now I understand why layer property of UIView is get-only, Many thanks. I think I successfully accepted your answer by clicking that tick.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `CAGradientLayer`, but instead of subclassing the `UIView`, just set it to the mask property of the layer:

```
let gradientMaskLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientMaskLayer.frame = maskedView.bounds

gradientMaskLayer.colors =  [UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor]
gradientMaskLayer.locations = [0.8, 1]

maskedView.layer.mask = gradientMaskLayer
```